# Random response or response from a set

Tags: mailchimp

Is there a way with mailchimp that you can set up an automated trigger or workflow that sends a different response based on criteria in the trigger, or just randomly?

The use-case is customer signs up to see what Villain they would be. The workflow triggered from that would send them a response including 1 of 20 possible variations.  The next person following the same work flow would receive a different response.

Comment: Mailchimp features vary according to the pricing plan, ref https://mailchimp.com/pricing/marketing/. Please add more details, including the pricing plan that you have. Also, showing what you have tried will be a good idea.

Comment: By the way, Mailchimp features might be extended by integrating it with other tools. If you are looking for a tool to be integrated with Mailchimp, the best is to ask for a software recommendation in [softwarerecs.se].